# come out of condition if keypress event is false

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tinymce, keyboard-events

I have seen many solutions on stackoverflow but none of them are giving me the right output. I am using key events for my textarea in order to validate the maxcount. I have written code which is not working as expected. In html I am using maxlength as its not effective for tinyMCE v3. So writing keyboard events to handle it.

```
            setup: function(editor)
        {
             editor.onKeyUp.add(function(evt)
            {
                        var max = 10;
                        var inputRichTextArea = $(editor.getBody()).text();
                        var len = inputRichTextArea.length;
                        var char = max - len;
                        if(char >= 0)
                        {
                            $(tinyMCE.activeEditor.getContainer()).find("#"+editor.id+"_path_row").html("Remaining characters: "+(char));
                        }
                        $(editor.getBody()).keypress(function (e) {
                            if (len >= max) {
                                return false;
                            tinyMCE.activeEditor.selection.setContent(inputRichTextArea.substring(0, max));
                            tinyMCE.activeEditor.focus();
                            e.cancelBubble = true;
                        } 
                    });
```

});
}

In this code I am unable to edit back the content when the len < max. backspace is working good but I event is not checking the if condition

[image]

Comment: Why there are still some statements after the return statement ?

Comment: I have tried something out It belongs to tinymce to set content in the frame I have tried it